# Mysql Many to Many Select with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have search but i dont solve my problems.
I have a many to many relationship.

3 tables:

```
groups_mail | groups_mail_j (joint table) | mails    
id, name    | mail_id, groupe_id          | id, name
```

I dont know how select all the emails for my groupe ID=1

Thx.

Comment: Any decent beginners book or tutorial would be able to help with that.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. Anyways this is what I have understood based on the question.

Your having 3 tables mails, groups_mail, groups_mail_j

You want to join all the tables and get all the records based on mails-> id column.

If above is the required on than you can do that by the following

```
SELECT m.id mailid, m.name AS email, gm.name AS groupname, gm.id AS groupmailid
FROM mails AS m
INNER JOIN groups_mail_j AS gmj ON gmj.mail_id = m.id
INNER JOIN groups_mail AS gm ON gm.id = gmj.groupe_id
WHERE m.id = 1
```

Here I have used the custom selectors. You can use any selector ie specific column of tables by using the alias of that table.

Okay so in-case you want to show all the mail-ids for the selected group then use the following query. No need to put the mail_id because if you knew mail id then you wouldn't have to query again.

```
SELECT m.name AS email
FROM mails AS m
INNER JOIN groups_mail_j AS gmj ON gmj.mail_id = m.id
INNER JOIN groups_mail AS gm ON gm.id = gmj.groupe_id
WHERE gmj.groupe_id = 1
```

Here 1 in hard coded in case you can user $group_id

Please check your spelling whether is **group_id** or **groupe_id**

Comment: Humm this my PHP code is more simple for you to undestand:
The querie is $getemails https://pastebin.com/HQQWrdTa

Comment: Hi can you please post an example of input and output required in the question so that I can help you better.

Comment: In my pastebin you can i see i get groups, groups have many email and emails many groups.
I want to show all the emails in a selected group.